# Kendo UI Grid FormGroup Custom Validation - DropdownList Controlled Validation

Tags: angular, typescript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I was attempting to modify the FormGroup validation of the FormGroup assigned to a Kendo Grid when one of the items in the dataItem is modified.  The logic is that:
If the selected AuthType is Basic, username and password should be 'required' by the form validation.
If the selected AuthType is QueryString, queryString should be 'required' by the form validation.
If the selected AuthType is AuthorizationHeader, authorizationHeader should be 'required' by the form validation.

This issue was, after updating the FormGroup, the validation no longer seems to function properly.  The old validations are still being honored, and when the selection for the AuthType is changed, the validations for the now hidden fields then prevents the form from being submitted.

He is my code:
web-connections.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ConnectionService } from '../connections.service';
import { SourceTypeService } from '../source-type-selector/source-type.service';
import { DialogSettings, DialogService, DialogAction } from '@progress/kendo-angular-dialog';
import { CategoryService } from 'src/app/category/category.service';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'web-connections',
  templateUrl: './web-connections.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./web-connections.component.css']
})
export class WebConnectionsComponent {
  webConnections = [];
  itemBeingEdited = {};
  editedRowIndex = 0;
  editedConnection = {};
  filteredWebConnections: any[];
  formGroup: FormGroup;

  selectedSourceType;
  selectedCategory: any;

  WEBAuthorizationEnum = [
    {name: "None", value:0},
    {name: "Basic", value:1},
    {name: "QueryString", value:2},
    {name: "AuthorizationHeader", value:3}
  ]

  subscriptions = [];
  constructor(private service: ConnectionService, 
    private sourceTypeService: SourceTypeService,
    private categoryService: CategoryService,
    private dialogService: DialogService) {
    this.subscriptions.push(this.sourceTypeService.selectedSourceType.subscribe(x => {
      this.selectedSourceType = x;
      this.UpdateData();
    }));
    this.subscriptions.push(this.categoryService.selectedCategory.subscribe(x => {
      this.selectedCategory = x;
      this.UpdateData();
    }));
    this.subscriptions.push(this.service.connections.subscribe(c => {
      this.webConnections = c.filter(x => x && x.sourceTypeID == 2);  
      this.UpdateData();    
    }));
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.subscriptions.forEach(x => x.unsubscribe());
  }

  AuthType(authType) {
    return this.WEBAuthorizationEnum[authType].name;
  }

  UpdateData() {
    if (this.webConnections != null && this.selectedCategory != null) {
      this.filteredWebConnections = this.webConnections.filter(x => x.categoryID == this.selectedCategory.categoryID);
    }
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.service.RefreshIfOld();
  }

  public addHandler({sender}) {
    this.closeEditor(sender);
    this.formGroup = this.createFormGroup({});
    sender.addRow(this.formGroup);
  }

  public editHandler({sender, rowIndex, dataItem}) {
    this.closeEditor(sender);
    this.itemBeingEdited = {...dataItem};
    this.editedRowIndex = rowIndex;
    this.editedConnection = Object.assign({}, dataItem);
    this.formGroup = this.createFormGroup(dataItem);
    sender.editRow(rowIndex, this.formGroup);
  }

  public cancelHandler({sender, rowIndex}) {
    this.closeEditor(sender, rowIndex);
  }

  grid;
  private closeEditor(grid, rowIndex = this.editedRowIndex) {
    grid.closeRow(rowIndex);
    this.resetItem(this.editedConnection);
    this.editedRowIndex = undefined;
    this.editedConnection = undefined;
  }


  public saveHandler({sender, rowIndex, formGroup, isNew}) {
    this.service.save(formGroup.value, isNew);
    sender.closeRow(rowIndex);
  }

  public resetItem(item) {
    item = {...this.itemBeingEdited};
  }

  public removeHandler({dataItem}) {
    var dialog = new DialogSettings();
    dialog.title = 'Confirm Delete';
    dialog.content =  "Are you sure you want to delete?  Deleting a Connection will ALL DATA that is currently associated with it. (Requests, DataMaps, Jobs, etc).";
    var actionYes = new DialogAction();
    actionYes.primary = true;
    actionYes.text = "Yes";
    var actionNo = new DialogAction();
    actionNo.primary = false;
    actionNo.text = "No";
    dialog.actions = [actionYes, actionNo];
    this.dialogService.open(dialog).result.subscribe((actionResult : any) => {
      if (actionResult.text == "Yes") {
        this.service.remove(dataItem);
      }
    });
  }

  fieldForEdit;
  fieldForEditValue;
  showExpressionEditor = false;
  openEditorDialog(fieldName) {
    this.fieldForEdit = fieldName;
    this.fieldForEditValue = this.formGroup.get(this.fieldForEdit).value;
    this.showExpressionEditor = true;
  }

  updateFieldForEdit(value) {
    this.formGroup.get(this.fieldForEdit).setValue(value);
    this.fieldForEdit = undefined;
    this.fieldForEditValue = undefined;
  }

  resetValidators() {    
    this.formGroup.controls['username'].clearValidators();
    this.formGroup.controls['username'].setErrors(null);
    this.formGroup.controls['username'].setValue(null);
    this.formGroup.controls['password'].clearValidators();
    this.formGroup.controls['password'].setErrors(null);
    this.formGroup.controls['password'].setValue(null);
    this.formGroup.controls['queryString'].clearValidators();
    this.formGroup.controls['queryString'].setErrors(null);
    this.formGroup.controls['queryString'].setValue(null);
    this.formGroup.controls['authorizationHeader'].clearValidators();
    this.formGroup.controls['authorizationHeader'].setErrors(null);
    this.formGroup.controls['authorizationHeader'].setValue(null);
    if (this.formGroup.get('authType').value == 1) {
      this.formGroup.controls['username'].setValidators(Validators.required);
      this.formGroup.controls['password'].setValidators(Validators.required);
    }
    if (this.formGroup.get('authType').value == 2) {
      this.formGroup.controls['queryString'].setValidators(Validators.required);
    }
    if (this.formGroup.get('authType').value == 3) {
      this.formGroup.controls['authorizationHeader'].setValidators(Validators.required);
    }    
    this.formGroup.controls['username'].updateValueAndValidity();
    this.formGroup.controls['password'].updateValueAndValidity();
    this.formGroup.controls['queryString'].updateValueAndValidity();
    this.formGroup.controls['authorizationHeader'].updateValueAndValidity();
    this.formGroup.updateValueAndValidity();
  }

  createFormGroup = dataItem => new FormGroup({
    "uri":new FormControl(dataItem.uri, Validators.required),
    "name": new FormControl(dataItem.name, Validators.required),
    "authType": new FormControl(dataItem.authType, Validators.required),
    "username": new FormControl(dataItem.username),
    "password": new FormControl(dataItem.password),
    "queryString": new FormControl(dataItem.queryString),
    "authorizationHeader": new FormControl(dataItem.authorizationHeader),
    "sourceTypeID": new FormControl(this.selectedSourceType.sourceTypeID),
    "categoryID": new FormControl(this.selectedCategory.categoryID)
  });
}
```

web-connections.component.html

```
<expression-editor-dialog *ngIf="showExpressionEditor == true" [(show)]="showExpressionEditor"
  [expression]="fieldForEditValue" (expressionChange)="updateFieldForEdit($event)"></expression-editor-dialog>

<kendo-grid [data]="filteredWebConnections" [height]="400" (edit)="editHandler($event)" (cancel)="cancelHandler($event)"
  (save)="saveHandler($event)" (remove)="removeHandler($event)" (add)="addHandler($event)">
  <ng-template kendoGridToolbarTemplate>
    <button kendoGridAddCommand title="Add {{selectedSourceType? selectedSourceType.description : ''}} Connection"
      icon="plus" [primary]="true">Add {{selectedTab}} Connection</button>
  </ng-template>
  <kendo-grid-column field="uri" title="API URI" width="280"></kendo-grid-column>
  <kendo-grid-column field="name" title="Name" width="200"></kendo-grid-column>
  <kendo-grid-column field="authType" title="Auth Type" width="150">
    <ng-template kendoGridEditTemplate let-dataItem="dataItem" >
      <kendo-dropdownlist [data]="WEBAuthorizationEnum" (selectionChange)="resetValidators()" [popupSettings]="{width: 280}" textField="name"
        valueField="value" valuePrimitive="true" name="authType" [formControl]="formGroup?.get('authType')"></kendo-dropdownlist>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem="dataItem">
      {{AuthType(dataItem.authType)}}
    </ng-template>
  </kendo-grid-column>
  <kendo-grid-column field="username" title="Username" width="150">
    <ng-template kendoGridEditTemplate let-dataItem="dataItem"  let-column="column" >
      <input [hidden]="dataItem.authType != 1" placeholder="Username" kendoTextBox [formControl]="formGroup?.get(column.field)"
        name="username"/>
    </ng-template>
  </kendo-grid-column>
  <kendo-grid-column field="password" title="Password" width="150">
    <ng-template kendoGridEditTemplate let-dataItem="dataItem" let-column="column">
      <input [hidden]="dataItem.authType != 1" placeholder="Password" kendoTextBox [formControl]="formGroup?.get(column.field)"
        name="password"/>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem="dataItem">
      <span *ngIf="dataItem.password != null">*******</span>
    </ng-template>
  </kendo-grid-column>
  <kendo-grid-column field="queryString" title="Query String" width="150">
    <ng-template kendoGridEditTemplate let-dataItem="dataItem"  let-column="column">
      <input [hidden]="dataItem.authType != 2" placeholder="Query String" kendoTextBox [formControl]="formGroup?.get(column.field)"
        name="queryString" class="withButton"/>
      <button [hidden]="dataItem.authType != 2" class="withInput" kendoButton title="Edit With Expression Editor" icon="pencil"
        (click)="openEditorDialog('queryString')"></button>
    </ng-template>
  </kendo-grid-column>
  <kendo-grid-column field="authorizationHeader" title="Authorization Header" width="150">
    <ng-template kendoGridEditTemplate let-dataItem="dataItem"  let-column="column">
      <input [hidden]="dataItem.authType != 3" placeholder="Authorization Header" kendoTextBox
      [formControl]="formGroup?.get(column.field)" name="authorizationHeader" class="withButton"/>
      <button [hidden]="dataItem.authType != 3" kendoButton title="Edit With Expression Editor" class="withInput" icon="pencil"
        (click)="openEditorDialog('authorizationHeader')"></button>
    </ng-template>
  </kendo-grid-column>
  <kendo-grid-command-column autoSize="false" width="78">
    <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate  let-isNew="isNew">
      <button kendoGridEditCommand [primary]="true" icon="pencil"></button>
      <button kendoGridRemoveCommand icon="trash"></button>
      <button [title]="isNew ? 'Add' : 'Update'" kendoGridSaveCommand [primary]="true" icon="floppy" [disabled]="formGroup?.invalid"></button>
      <button [title]="isNew ? 'Discard' : 'Cancel'" kendoGridCancelCommand icon="cancel"></button>
    </ng-template>
  </kendo-grid-command-column>
</kendo-grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it turns out I wound up finding the solution to my own problem.

The solution was implementing a custom validator for the functions that needed to have validation that reacted to its own dataItem.

I also had to implement a little bit of code in the enum selection to set the FormGroup value of authType and trigger the initial validation of the custom validated fields and reset any existing values in those fields.

see the solution below:

in component.html:

```
<kendo-grid-column field="authType" title="Auth Type" width="150">
    <ng-template kendoGridEditTemplate let-dataItem="dataItem" >
      <kendo-dropdownlist [data]="WEBAuthorizationEnum" (selectionChange)="resetValidators($event)" [popupSettings]="{width: 280}" textField="name"
        valueField="value" valuePrimitive="true" name="authType" [formControl]="formGroup?.get('authType')"></kendo-dropdownlist>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem="dataItem">
      {{AuthType(dataItem.authType)}}
    </ng-template>
  </kendo-grid-column>
```

in component.ts:

```
requiredIfAuthType = (authType: number) => (control: AbstractControl) =>  {
    if (this.formGroup && this.formGroup.controls && this.formGroup.controls.authType && this.formGroup.controls.authType.value) {
      if (this.formGroup.controls.authType.value == authType && (!control.value || control.value == "")) {
        return {required: true};
      }
    }
    return null;
  }

  resetValidators(authType) {
    this.formGroup.controls.authType.setValue(authType.value);
    this.formGroup.controls.username.reset();
    this.formGroup.controls.password.reset();
    this.formGroup.controls.queryString.reset();
    this.formGroup.controls.authorizationHeader.reset();
    this.formGroup.controls.username.updateValueAndValidity();
    this.formGroup.controls.password.updateValueAndValidity();
    this.formGroup.controls.queryString.updateValueAndValidity();
    this.formGroup.controls.authorizationHeader.updateValueAndValidity();
  }


  createFormGroup = dataItem => new FormGroup({
    "uri":new FormControl(dataItem.uri, Validators.required),
    "name": new FormControl(dataItem.name, Validators.required),
    "authType": new FormControl(dataItem.authType, Validators.required),
    "username": new FormControl(dataItem.username, this.requiredIfAuthType(1)),
    "password": new FormControl(dataItem.password, this.requiredIfAuthType(1)),
    "queryString": new FormControl(dataItem.queryString, this.requiredIfAuthType(2)),
    "authorizationHeader": new FormControl(dataItem.authorizationHeader, this.requiredIfAuthType(3)),
    "sourceTypeID": new FormControl(this.selectedSourceType.sourceTypeID),
    "categoryID": new FormControl(this.selectedCategory.categoryID),
  });
```

Thanks!